# No surname on passport and applying for Japanese Visa

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, japan, paperwork

I am an Indian student and am going to Japan for my Summer Internship this May. There is no Surname field on my Indian passport and only my single initial name, `XXXXX`, in the Given names field in passport. How should I fill the name fields in the Visa form then? Should I write my first name (Given name on passport) in the Surname field and `FNU` in the Given and middle names field?

[image]

My passport `Surname` field :

[image]

Comment: Just make it clear that you don't have a surname, e.g. write something like N/A or "without surname". Those forms are intended to be read by human beings and as long as they understand, you're fine.

Comment: Is it fine if I just leave the that field blank. They will understand right ? @XuanruiQi

Comment: Is there 'notes' section in the application? If so, clarify there why you did not specify your surname.

Comment: There is no 'notes' section. Please see the updated image of the visa application form. @OleksandrKravchuk

Comment: Please clarify the following: there is no 'Surname' field in your passport of it is empty?

Comment: Yes. The `Surname` field on my passport is empty. @OleksandrKravchuk Please see the image for my passport field as well.

Comment: @Jarvis Yes, since you'll give them your passport as well. If they are in doubt they could always verify against your passport.

Comment: @jarvis I am in the same situation. What did you end up doing when applying?

Comment: depends on the type of application too. What is your purpose of visit ? @user68169

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I just chit-chatted with an Indian colleague of mine, who advised the following.

You should put all of your middle names in the surname fields if you have any. If you don't, leave it blank and do **not** write N/A or anything similar there.

You may have issues booking your flight to Japan later on since many airlines' software does not allow to leave Surname field empty, but this is another story.

Comment: Thanks !! Just one more query. Since I am applying for internship visa, I have to submit income tax return of my father and there is a slight mismatch between his name on the return statement and his name on my passport. Will it cause any issue ?

Comment: I am sure it will. I would add a letter with detailed explanations to your application.

Comment: So in that letter, I should just explain that both the names belong to one person right? Do I also need to submit any proof along that?

Comment: Always submit proofs if you have any.

Comment: Ok, about the mismatch, the first and last names are same, and there is only a character difference in the middle name. And since the company is sponsoring my stay and travels there, will a slight mismatch cause issue?

Comment: I'm sure it won't if you provide them with legit explanations.